# Send data to my views.py: CSRF token missing

Tags: django

I have an html page which allows to send the contents of a csv file. From a javascript file I do different processing on the content. Then I would like to send to my view to add it to my database.

When i click on the button i get this error:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing.): /app/addDataInDB  
[11/Nov/2022 14:06:56] "POST /app/addDataInDB HTTP/1.1" 403 2506
```

**.html**

```
<form id="myForm" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" id="csvFile" accept=".csv" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
...
<script src="{% static 'js/readCSV.js' %}"></script>
```

**.js**

```
const form = document.getElementById('myForm')
form.addEventListener('submit', sendData);
function sendData(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const res = { 0:{"val1": 1, "val2":2}, 1:{"val1": 3, "val2":4}}
    let csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    //const postdata = { csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'addDataInDB',
        data: { 
             "result": res,  
              csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { alert("successfull") },
        failure: function () { alert("failure"); }
    })
}
```

**app/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views
urlpatterns =[ 
  path('page1', views.getDataFromCSV, name='gdfcsv'),
  re_path(r'^addDataInDB$', views.addDataInDB, name='addDataInDB'),]
```

**app/views.py**

```
def addDataInDB(request):
    if request.method == "POST": print(request.POST)
    

def getDataFromCSV(request):
    return render(request, 'getDataFromCSV.html', {})
```

Comment: According to your addDataDB view, you are not rendering that template

Comment: add csrf token in post data . `let csrf = $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();`
`postdata = { csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf }` with your additional required post data as well

Comment: @Hemal Patel Hello i put the code in `sendData(event){let csrf = ... ; const postdata = { csrfmiddlewaretoken : csrf } $.ajax({ ... data: { "result": res, postdata }, ...}) }` and I still have the same problem

Comment: @Hemal Patel I put directly  `csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf` in data and it's work. thank for your help.